# Background Image Is Not Responsive AFTER jQuery Sets CSS

Tags: jquery, background-image, responsiveness

I have a `div` element that will contain a different background image based on the size of the browser screen.

Here's an example of the CSS that will do the responsive work:

```
div {
    background-image: url(a.jpg);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    div {
        background-image: url(b.jpg);
    }
}
```

The example CSS above works fine until I use jQuery to set the background image. In other words, after jQuery sets the `background-image` of the `div`, the responsiveness no longer works.

It makes sense to me that the responsiveness stops working due to the fact that the browser doesn't know that I want to allow the responsiveness to continue working if/when the user resizes the browser window. However, in my case, I do want the resizing of the browser window to always overwrite the `background-image` that jQuery may have set prior to the resizing.

Is this solvable in CSS or will I need to manage this with a script? (Note: `!important` doesn't do the trick).

[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4du7ds4L/), you will see how the background-image changes appropriately when you resize the browser window. The responsiveness stops working if and only if you click one of the buttons.

Comment: Setting a style directly via the element’s `style` attribute (and that is what jQuery’s `.css()` does) always overwrites any other CSS rules, because it has the highest possible specificity. I’d suggest that you don’t use `.css()`, but change/add/remove the element’s class dynamically instead (which is in general the preferred way in most situations). However, I am not totally sure what result you actually expect, when what your media query that gets currently applied says contradicts your choice via button …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    $('div').removeAttr('style');
});
```

and if you want other style remain remove only background-image

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    $('div').css('background-image','');
});
```